# Devexpress XtraReport how to print more than one label for each DataSource row based on count field

Tags: dataset, devexpress, xtrareport

I'm printing labels for an inventory system using an XtraReport bound to a PartsInventory table.  Each row of the bound table contains a description of the part along with a count of the number of parts in inventory.  Currently using the XtraReport component, I am able to print one label for each row in the DataTable.  However, if I would like to print a label to stick on each physical part then a single row should print "count" number of identical labels. "count" is a field in each row signifying how many of each part are on hand.

Is there a best way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: It's pretty hard to give suggestion as you have shown no code whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, up until this point everything has been done visually and there isn't a whole lot of code.

Comment: Can you show an example of the data and how you want the actual report to look?  A mock-up would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. I gave up on XtraReport and just designed the label on a User Control and then drawstring() to a PrintDocument for each label. If I had stuck with XtraReport I would have probably just inherited from DataTable and write a custom fill() method to populate with one row for each actual label.  If anyone is interested in the solution I came up with to print lables just let me know.